# async and await , bit confusing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I am refereing to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) blog that explains usage of await and async keyword in .Net framework 4.5

I am trying to address following realtime scenario using these keywords

I have two devices Device1 and Device2.  These devices are connected to my computer using Serial port ( RS 232 ).  I have a windows application to which is capable of sending commands to these devices.
    Now, initially I have to start these two devices by sending specific RS-232 commands.  Now I can do this job simultaneously and update the UI accordingly.  Below is code to solve this scenario

```
public class Device1 
{
    public async Task<int> Start(int sec)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device1 started @ : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Task t = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(sec * 1000); });
        t.Start();
        await t;
        Console.WriteLine("Device1 finished @ : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        return 1;
    }         
}

public class Device2 
{
    public async Task<int> Start(int sec)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device2 started @ : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Task t = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(sec * 1000); });
        t.Start();
        await t;
        Console.WriteLine("Device2 finished @ : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        return 1;
    }       
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device2 d2= new Device2();
        Device1 d1= new Device1();

        await d2.Start(10);
        label1.Text = "d2 Started....";///It takes 10 sec to update this
        await d1.Start(5);///this line starts executing after 10 secs?  Why?
        label1.Text = "d1 Started...";

        MessageBox.Show("I am done...");///Get this message after 15 sec!!!
    }
```

Now my understanding was both `await d2.Start(10);` and `await d1.Start(5);` will run simultaneously and will update UI accordingly.  But thats not the case.  Having close look at Console.WriteLine statememts prove that its completely seqential call.
   Can someone throw more light on this?

Comment: Yes, you are making it sequential. Suppose Label1.Text has to show a value produced by d2.Start(). How could it do that before the call w as complete?  You did decouple it from the Main GUI thread though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for `async` newbies; it has links at the end to the best followup documentation.

In short, what's happening is that you are `await`ing the tasks. This will pause the method until those tasks complete. If you want to let them run concurrently, then you can save the tasks into variables (`t1`, `t2`) and then await them both (`await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);`).

P.S. don't use the `Task` constructor or `Task.Start` in `async` code; use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: Hi, many tutorials online say that as the awaitable is executing, a thread will be freed to do something else. First, does it mean that right after the await is called, a new thread will be created solely for the execution of awaitable? Second, the method that calls await cannot go on until the awaitable finishes itself. Also, await can only accept async method. This is my understand to it. Well then in this chain of await-async calls, nothing can be done while waiting because even if you go back to the first await, it is still awaiting! There must be some misunderstanding. Can you correct me?

Comment: @AndesLam: When an `await` decides to asynchronously wait, the current method *returns*. If the calling method also `await`s, then that method returns, and so on. Eventually a method will return to the .NET runtime, and at that point the thread is available for other work. Another thread [is not created](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 4):

The `await` keyword does not make the awaited tasks (the results of `d2.Start(10)` and `d1.Start(5)`, respectively) run in parallel. What it does is saying to the compiler "let the rest of this method run after the awaited tasks finishes" without blocking the thread.

You may want to read some introduction on the `async/await` keywords, e.g. [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)